# how to enable scrollbar in kendo ui grid

Tags: kendo-ui

I have created a kendo window with a grid inside it. I want to create a scroll bar on the grid only and not on the kendo window. I am unable to create the scroll bar on the grid.
Please suggest me the appropriate solution for this issue.

```
HTML part is as follows :
<html>
<body>
<div id = "mywindow">
<h1>Work Order</h1>
<div id="grid"></div>  
</div>  
<a href="#" id="btnGO">Go</a>
</body>
</html>
```

**javascript part is as follows :**

```
$(document).ready(function () {[screenshot for error in scrollbar][1]
jQuery('#mywindow').kendoWindow({
width:300,
height:400,
animation: false,
autoFocus: true,
visible:false,
resizable : false
});
$('#btnGO').click(function(){
$('#mywindow').data('kendoWindow').center().open();
});
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
height : 100,
selectable: "multiple cell",
allowCopy: true,
columns: [
{ field: "student", title: "student"},
{ field: "student", title:"Mins"}
],
scrollable : true,
dataSource : [
{student: 10,mins: 120},
{student: 11,mins:100},
{student: 12,mins: 90},
{student: 12,mins: 90},
{student: 12,mins: 90},
{student: 12,mins: 90},
{student: 12,mins: 90},
{student: 12,mins: 90},
{student: 12,mins: 90},
{student: 12,mins: 90}
]
});

$('#grid .k-grid-content').scroll(function () 
{ alert('I am scrolling ...');               });
});
```

**css part is as follows :**

```
.k-window  div.k-window-content
{
overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not know where is the logic, but if you initialize the the grid first, then the window it works...

Here are a sample in [Telerik Dojo](http://dojo.telerik.com/Eculo/2)

Answer (score 0):

Let's presume you want to have the kendo grid fill the remainder of kendo window after the `<H1>`.

Add a window `activate` event handler that will compute a height for the grid.  The desired height is `height of containing parent` - `top position of grid`.  NOTE: The containing parent is the content of the window.

```
jQuery('#mywindow').kendoWindow({
  ... ,
  activate: function (e) {
    var H = $("#grid").offsetParent().height(); // height of containing parent in which grid is placed
    var T = $("#grid").position().top; // top of grid relative to containing parent
    $("#grid").getKendoGrid().setOptions ({height: H-T});        
  },
  ...
});
```

Everything else is automatic and your grid will have scroll bars.

Also, in the question code, one of the columns is incorrectly specified:

```
  { field: "student", title:"Mins"}
```

if should be

```
  { field: "mins", title: "Mins"}
```

If you are still having a problem add more info to the question, such as Kendo version, browser and version, jQuery version.